# Inserting arabic characters into sql server database from grails

Tags: sql-server, grails, grails-orm

I have a grails application that is intended to insert arabic characters from interface to sql server database. First I did it with field type `varchar` but it appears `???????`. Then I found that the field type should be `nvarchar` but with, application simply fails to insert any row by giving the following error,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'smsCampaigner.dbo.message'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I know that this is constraints error that id cannot be null but this was not the case before changing the field type. Now I want to know whether we can specify fro `config.groovy` which encoding should be used in database ? any other type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you specify explicitly the type (varchar, nvarchar) you wanted for that variable in the domain class?

Answer (score 0):

here you go..

when you create the domain class use String type for that column and that's it. you could insert any character it will accept.

for example TestDomain.groovy

```
class TestDomain {
   String column1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can set up the collation of the database/table/column to use utf8_unicode_ci and if I am not wrong that is valid to save arabic chars. Not sure how to do it with SQL Server but it should be something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Change the collation of the database and tables and columns to `Arabic_CI_AS` 
In Sql Server management studio (SSMS), Execute :

```
ALTER DATABASE  DB06 COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
```

where DB06 is the name of the database.
right-click on table, then click design, then select the desired column, in its properties, choose the collation to `Arabic_CI_AS`

 by the way, the error :

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column

is not related to Arabic, this is because you are trying to insert NULL in the column that does not allow NULL.